# Advice on what shaders to use for stylised reptile skin?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders

So I'm practicing using shaders on animals and I thought I would start with reptile skin. Now I'm not ready to work with image textures yet, but I found a good example of what I'm going for in a pokemon from Pokken charizard.

[image] [image]
<sup>*Click to enlarge.*</sup>

That character they got in the shaders they use are beautiful. But I'm wondering what shaders I would need to use to get that effect. One is obviously the glossy, but after that I have no idea, does anyone else?

Comment: I'm sure these shaders can be created with just diffuse and glossy and their respective textures. For any other context, you would also use SSS, especially for the wings.

Comment: IMO,  a lot of the liveliness in this rendering is the result of 2D line art / 2D texturing. For example [these highlights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrwET.jpg) look to me as if they have been painted in.. they are not the result of a 3D object responding to light as a result of PBR, and would not persist in the round, using simple shaders. To get _exactly_ this feel, I think you would have to look at interesting, and subtle, use of toon/NPR techniques..

Answer (score 2):

[image: final]

For simple procedural recreation of this material you can use **Principled BSDF** shader with some simple textures:

[image: Nodes]

As a color I've used only **Noise** texture with **Color Ramp** to give a little variation for it. In your example texture is indeed hand painted.

The reflective part is **Clearcoat** and **Roughness** dropped to .3

Green border marks bumps created from **Voronoi** textures. I've used them as **Normal** and **Clearcoat Normal**.

The light rim is made by using two big **Area Lamps** placed behind model:

[image: lights]

Comment: Wow thanks, that really helps, ya I'm working on panting a texture, still not sure what I'm going to do about scales yet but this is a start

Comment: @bpbutcher look closely at the image, I've added some bumps to mimic scales. You can make them more visible by changing Strength in Bump node.